# I have a problem using JFrame to print a table for multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe

I have been trying to print all the information from the arrays I ask for in the code, but I'm not able to find a way to print it all in a table once the user doesn't wants to evaluate more people.

I've tried to use some solutions that I have seen here but at least I haven't been able to understand them.

All I need is that the information saved on the multiple arrays that are asked by `JOptionPane` all them saved and printed into a LIST.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class ProyectoFinal extends JFrame {

    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
          int opcfinal = 0;
            int n = 0; //SE DETERMINA EL TAMAñO DEL ARREGLO, PARA ALMACENAR LOS DATOS DE NOMBRE Y CEDULA
            String[] name = new String[1000];  // SE CREA UN ARREGLO PARA GUARDAR LOS NOMBRES CON PLAZAS ILIMATADAS PARA NO TENER PROBLEMAS DE COMPILACION
            String[] cedula = new String[1000]; // SE CREA UN ARREGLO PARA GUARDAR LOS NUMEROS DE CEDULA CON PLAZAS ILIMTADAS PARA NO TENER PROBLEMAS DE COMPILACION
            int[] puntos = new int[1000];   // SE CREA EL ARREGLO QUE ALMACENARA LOS PUNTOS DE LOS ESTUDIANTES EVALUADOS
            int[] rescorrect = new int[1000];   // SE CREA EL ARREGLO QUE GUARDARA LA CANTIDAD DE RESPUESTAS CORRECTAS QUE TUVO EL ESTUDIANTE
            int[] status = new int[1000]; // SE GUARDA EL VALOR DE TIPO INTEGER QUE DETERMINARA SI EL TEXTO A MOSTRAR SERA APROBADO/RECHAZADO
            do { // SE CREA UN CICLO REPETITIVO QUE EVALUE LA OPCION DEL USUARIO EN EL SHOWCONFIRMDIALOG
                name[n] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Escriba su nombre: ","Instituto Superior Informático Panameño", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);// SE PIDE POR TECLADO EL NOMBRE
                cedula[n] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite su cedula", "Instituto Superior Informático Panameño", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);// SE PIDE POR TECLADO LA CEDULA
            for (int i = 0; i<1; i++)   { // SE CREA UN CICLO REPETITIVO CON AUMENTO DE 1 PARA EVALUAR LAS PREGUNTAS UNA SOLA VEZ POR ESTUDIANTE Y GUARDAR LOS VALORES DENTRO DE LOS ARREGLOS DECLARADOS
                int p1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "En programacion, una variable es:" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Informacion Almacenada  \n2) Un numero  \n3) Un Contador", "Pregunta 1", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p1== 1) { // SE CREA UN CONDICIONAL QUE EVALUA SI LA RESPUESTA ES CORRECTA
                  
                    puntos[i] = 6 + puntos[i]; // SE AUMENTA LOS PUNTOS EN CASO DE LA RESPUESTA SER CORRECTA
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i]; // SE ALMACENA LA INFORMACION DE QUE EL ESTUDIANTE TUVO UNA RESPUESTA CORRECTA Y SE SUMA A LAS ANTERIORES PARA LLEVAR UN CONTROL.
                    
                }else if(p1!=1) { // Y SE CREA LA CONDICION ACERCA DE QUE HACER EN CASO DE QUE LA RESPUESTA SEA INCORRECTA
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i]; //DE TENER UNA RESPUESTA EQUIVOCADA, LOS PUNTOS SE QUEDAN COMO ESTABAN Y LA CANTIDAD DE RESPUESTAS CORRECTAS NO AUMENTA.
                  
                }
          
                int p2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Que es un hacker?:" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Un delincuente informatico  \n2) Un programa de Facebook  \n3) Experto en Tecnologia ", "Pregunta 2", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p2==3) {
                  
                    puntos[i] = 6 + puntos[i];
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                }else if(p2!=3) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
                       
                }
                
                int p3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Que es un malware? :" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Software Malicioso  \n2) Virus de Celular  \n3) Un Trino de un Politico en Campaña ", "Pregunta 3", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p3== 1) {
                  
                    puntos[i] = 6 + puntos[i];
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                }else if(p3!=1) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
                  
                }
                int p4 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Que es Python? :" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Una Serpiente  \n2) Un Lenguaje de Programacion  \n3) Un arma ", "Pregunta 4", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p4== 2) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 6 + puntos[i];
                  
                }else if(p4!=2) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
                  
                }
                
                int p5 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "La Ram es:" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Capacidad de almacenamiento  \n2) Chip de ayuda al Procesador  \n3) Rama de la tecnologia que estudia el hardware ", "Pregunta 5", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p5== 2) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 6 + puntos[i];
                  
                }else if(p5!=2) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
                
                }
                int p6 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Que es minecraft?" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) VideoJuego de supervivencia  \n2) Metodo chino de almacenamiento de datos  \n3) Bomba atomica ", "Pregunta 6", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p6== 1) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 6 + puntos[i];
                  
                }else if(p6!=1) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
                
                }
                int p7 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Que es el machine learning:" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Enseñar a las maquinas a hacer cosas  \n2) Programar maquinas para que usen algoritmos  \n3) Todo aquello que podemos aprender de una maquina ", "Pregunta 7", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p7== 2) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 6 + puntos[i];
                  
                }else if(p7!=2) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
                
                }
                int p8 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Que es Realidad Aumentada:" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Tecnologia de inmersion  \n2) Protocolo de Mejora a la vista humana  \n3) Vision de un entorno fisico al mundo real, a traves de un dispositivo ", "Pregunta 8", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p8== 3) {
                  
                    puntos[i] = 6 + puntos[i];
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                }else if(p8!=3) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
                
                }
                int p9 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Para que se utilizan los Bit-Coins:" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Apostar en Casinos  \n2) Realizar Pagos Online de forma segura  \n3) Comprar entradas de cine ", "Pregunta 9", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p9== 2) {
                  
                    puntos[i] = 6 + puntos[i];
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                }else if(p9!=2) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
                
                }
                int p10 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Que es un String:" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Una variable de tipo cadena  \n2) Una cuerda  \n3) Un culumpio ", "Pregunta 10", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p10== 1) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 6 + puntos[i];
                  
                }else if(p10!=1) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
                
                }
                int p11 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "El orden de los factores no altera:" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) La Formula Cuadratica  \n2) El Producto  \n3) La Division ", "Pregunta 11", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p11== 2) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 4 + puntos[i];
                  
                }else if(p11!=2) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
                
                }
                int p12 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "En la jerarquia de Operadores, cual de los siguientes signos tiene prioridad?:" // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                            + "\n1) *  \n2) -  \n3) + ", "Pregunta 12", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p12== 1) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 4 + puntos[i];
                  
                }else if(p12!=1) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
                
                }
                int p13 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Cuanto vale Pi?: " // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) 3.1315  \n2) 3.1416  \n3) 3.1415 ", "Pregunta 13", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p13== 3) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                puntos[i] = 4 + puntos[i];
              
                }else if(p13!=3) {
                puntos[i] = puntos[i];
            
                }
                int p14 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Como se denomina un Triangulo con sus 3 lados iguales: " // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                    + "\n1) Isosceles  \n2) Escaleno  \n3) Equilatero ", "Pregunta 14", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p14== 3) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 4 + puntos[i];
          
                }else if(p14!=3) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
        
                }
                int p15 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Como se denomina un Triangulo con sus 3 lados diferentes: " // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Isosceles  \n2) Escaleno  \n3) Equilatero ", "Pregunta 15", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p15== 2) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 4 + puntos[i];
        
                }else if(p15!=2) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
    
                }
                int p16 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What DOB stands for?: " // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Date of Birth  \n2) Date of Bird  \n3) Donuts Online Business ", "Pregunta 16", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p16== 1) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 4 + puntos[i];
        
                }else if(p16!=1) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
    
                }
                int p17 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the plural form for Child?: " // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Childs  \n2) Childes  \n3) Children ", "Pregunta 17", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p17== 3) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 4 + puntos[i];
        
                }else if(p17!=3) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
    
                }
                int p18 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "English Language haves it's origins from: " // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) United States  \n2) German  \n3) British ", "Pregunta 18", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p18== 2) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 4 + puntos[i];
        
                }else if(p18!=2) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
    
                }
                int p19 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "To be Verb for He: " // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) Is  \n2) are  \n3) Am ", "Pregunta 19", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)); 
                if (p19== 1) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 4 + puntos[i];
        
                }else if(p19!=1) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
    
                }
                int p20 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is TOEFL: " // SE PIDE LA RESPUESTA POR TECLADO SEGUN OPCIONES.
                        + "\n1) English Test  \n2) STD  \n3) Cookie brand ", "Pregunta 20", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
                if (p20== 1) {
                    rescorrect[i] = 1 + rescorrect[i];
                    puntos[i] = 4 + puntos[i];
        
                }else if(p20!=1) {
                    puntos[i] = puntos[i];
    
                }
                
                if (puntos[i]>=71) { // SE CREA LA CONDICIONAL PARA DETERMINAR SI EL ESTUDIANTE FUE APROBADO/RECHAZADO
                    status[i] = 1;
                }else if(puntos[i]<71) {
                    status[i] = 0;
                }
                
                
                
                opcfinal = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea Continuar?"); //DETERMINA SI HAY OTRA PERSONA A EVALUAR O NO.
              
                
                ++n;
        //ESTO CIERRA EL CICLO DE PREGUNTAS
                }
              
        } while(opcfinal == 0);
       
            Object[][] info = {
                    {puntos[n],name[n],cedula[n],status[n]}
            };
            
            String[] header = {"Estudiante No","Nombre","Cedula","Puntos Obtenidos","Status"};
            
            JTable table = new JTable(info, header);
            
            Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN,12);
            
            table.setFont(font);
            table.setRowHeight(n);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(600,400);
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
           for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, puntos[i]);
           }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Could you make this example just using an Array without the JOptionPanes to accumulate information? This is pretty hard to follow.

Comment: Since this is a school project, I'm just going to give you general hints.  Create a Student class to hold the name, cedula, puntos, rescorrect, and status for each student.  Create a Question class with a question, a java.util.List of answers, and correct answer, so you can use the same JOptionPane 20 times instead of creating 20 JOptionPanes.  Create your application model separate from your Swing view.  After completing a List of  Students, it should be a simple matter to create a JTable inside a JScrollPane placed in the center of a JFrame to display the student information.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), should help you see how to create and populate a JTable.

Answer (score 2):

## Introduction

Since this is an older question, I decided to tackle the question by completely reorganizing / rewriting the OP's code.

I created a complete GUI.  Here are a series of images showing the GUI.

This is the student page of the GUI.  This is where a student enters his name and student ID,  Most of the text of this GUI is Spanish.  I was surprised when I was transcribing that the last few questions were in English.

[image: GUI 1]

This is the question and answer page of the GUI.  The number of questions loaded into the application model is the number of questions that will be asked.  The questions are asked in the order that they are loaded into the application model.  The answers are shuffled so they appear in random order.

The student answers the question by selecting one of the radio buttons on the right, then left-clicking on the Continue button.

[image: GUI 2]

This is one of the questions from the middle.  There are 20 questions in total.

[image: GUI 3]

The student returns to the student panel after the test is completed.  The student's score is returned at the bottom of the panel.

[image: GUI 4]

To access the secret table of student scores, you have to enter "111111" as the student ID number.

[image: GUI 5]

And here's the secret table of student scores.

[image: GUI 6]

## Explanation

When I create a complex Swing application, I use the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the application at a time.

### Model

I started by creating the application model.  I created a `Student` class, a `Question` class, and a `ProjectModel` class.  All three of these classes are plain Java getter / setter classes.

The `ProjectModel` class is the main application model.  It contains a `java.util.List` of `Student` instances and a `java.util.List` class of `Question` instances.  All references to `List` in the rest of this answer refer to `java.util.List`.

The `createQuestionsFactory` method of the `ProjectModel` class creates all of the test questions. The method is 127 lines long.  By creating a `Question` class and a List of `Question` instances, we can create one question panel and reuse it.  I could have referenced the correct answer, rather than copying it, but I copied the correct answer so the code would be easier to verify and understand.  A real system would have panels for entering tests and questions and saving the tests to a database, as well as retrieving tests.

The `Question` class consists of a `String` question, a `List` of `String` possible answers, a `String` correct answer, and an `int` value.  We group these fields together in one class so we don't have to keep track of these values separately.

The number of possible answers for a question is not fixed, although all the questions should have the same number of possible answers.  The view code would have to be more complicated if questions had different numbers of possible answers.

The `Student` class keeps the fields together that pertain to a student.  This class will become important when we populate the `JTable` of student scores.

### View

The view consists of a `JFrame`, with the main `JPanel`.  The main `JPanel` uses a `CardLayout` to switch from one `JPanel` to another.

The three subordinate `JPanels` are a student `JPanel`, a question `JPanel`, and a table `JPanel`.  The first two subordinate `JPanels` uses a `GridBagLayout`.  The last subordinate `JPanel` uses a `BorderLayout`.

The `ProyectoFinal` class starts with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing application creates and executes the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

The `ProyectoFinal` class constructor creates one instance of the `ProjectModel` class.  Generally, you create an instance of the model before you create the view.

The `run` method of the `ProyectoFinal` class creates the `JFrame`.  These methods have to be called in this order.

The `createMainPanel` method creates the main `JPanel` using the `CardLayout`.

The `createStudentPanel` method and the `createQuestionPanel` method create their `JPanel` using the `GridBagLayout`.  The `createTablePanel` method creates its `JPanel` using the `BorderLayout`.

The `updateQuestionPanel` and `updateTablePanel` methods update the question `JPanel` and the table `JPanel`, respectively.

### Controller

The controller classes are all anonymous.  I had already created 4 classes.

Each `JButton` has an anonymous controller class.  The `actionListener` methods of the anonymous controller classes are where the application model is updated and the main `JPanel` is switched to the appropriate `JPanel` card.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  Minimal, it is not.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ProyectoFinal implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ProyectoFinal());
    }
    
    private int questionCount;
    
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    
    private JLabel questionTitleLabel;
    private JLabel studentMessageLabel;
    
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    
    private JTextField nameField;
    private JTextField cedulaField;
    private JTextField questionField;
    
    private JTextField[] answerFields;
    
    private ProjectModel model;
    
    private Question question;
    
    private Student student;
    
    public ProyectoFinal() {
        this.model = new ProjectModel();
        this.questionCount = 0;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Proyecto Final");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        
        panel.add(createStudentPanel(), "Student");
        panel.add(createQuestionPanel(), "Question");
        panel.add(createTablePanel(), "Table");
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void clearStudentPanel(String message) {
        nameField.setText("");
        cedulaField.setText("");
        studentMessageLabel.setText(message);
    }
    
    public JPanel createStudentPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        
        int count = model.getQuestions().size();
        
        String instructions = "<html>Esta es una prueba automatizada. Después "
                + "de enviar su nombre y número de identificación "
                + "<br />de estudiante, se le mostrarán " + count + " preguntas "
                + "de opción múltiple. Sus respuestas se calificarán "
                + "<br />y se les asignará una calificación.";
        
        JLabel instructionsLabel = new JLabel(instructions);
        instructionsLabel.setFont(panel.getFont().deriveFont(14f));
        instructionsLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.add(instructionsLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Escriba su nombre:");
        panel.add(nameLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        nameField = new JTextField(40);
        panel.add(nameField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel cedulaLabel = new JLabel("<html>Escriba su número de"
                + "<br />identificación de estudiante:");
        panel.add(cedulaLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        cedulaField = new JTextField(40);
        panel.add(cedulaField, gbc);
        
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton button = new JButton("Enviar");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                String cedula = cedulaField.getText().trim();
                String name = nameField.getText().trim();
                
                if (cedula.equals("111111")) {
                    updateTablePanel();
                    CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) mainPanel.getLayout();
                    layout.show(mainPanel, "Table");
                    return;
                }
                
                if (cedula.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty()) {
                    return;
                } 
                    
                ProyectoFinal.this.student = new Student(cedula, name);
                model.addStudent(student);
                CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) mainPanel.getLayout();
                layout.show(mainPanel, "Question");
            }
        });
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridy++;
        studentMessageLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        studentMessageLabel.setFont(panel.getFont().deriveFont(14f));
        studentMessageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.add(studentMessageLabel, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateQuestionPanel() {
        this.question = model.getQuestion(questionCount);
        
        questionTitleLabel.setText("Pregunta " + (questionCount + 1));
        questionField.setText(question.getQuestion());
        
        List<String> answers = question.getShuffledAnswers();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
            answerFields[i].setText(answers.get(i));
        }
    }
    
    public JPanel createQuestionPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        
        this.question = model.getQuestion(questionCount);
        
        questionTitleLabel = new JLabel("Pregunta 1");
        questionTitleLabel.setFont(panel.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
        questionTitleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.add(questionTitleLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel instructionsLabel = new JLabel("Seleccione la respuesta "
                + "más apropiada y haga clic izquierdo en el botón Continuar");
        instructionsLabel.setFont(panel.getFont().deriveFont(14f));
        instructionsLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.add(instructionsLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel questionLabel = new JLabel("Pregunta:");
        panel.add(questionLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx++;
        questionField = new JTextField(60);
        questionField.setEditable(false);
        questionField.setText(question.getQuestion());
        panel.add(questionField, gbc);
        
        List<String> answers = question.getShuffledAnswers();
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        
        ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        answerFields = new JTextField[answers.size()];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
            String answer = answers.get(i);
            
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            JLabel numberLabel = new JLabel((i + 1) + ")");
            panel.add(numberLabel, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx++;
            answerFields[i] = new JTextField(60);
            answerFields[i].setEditable(false);
            answerFields[i].setText(answer);
            panel.add(answerFields[i], gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx++;
            JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton();
            buttonGroup.add(radioButton);
            panel.add(radioButton, gbc);
        }
        
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton button = new JButton("Continuar");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                Enumeration<AbstractButton> list = buttonGroup.getElements();
                
                int index = 0;
                Iterator<AbstractButton> iterator = list.asIterator();
                while (list.hasMoreElements()) {
                    JRadioButton button = (JRadioButton) iterator.next();
                    if (button.isSelected()) {  
                        String answer = question.getAnswer(index);
                        if (question.isAnswerCorrect(answer)) {
                            student.addPuntos(question.getPuntos());
                            student.addRescorrect();
                        }
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                buttonGroup.clearSelection();
                questionCount++;
                
                if (questionCount < model.getQuestions().size()) {
                    updateQuestionPanel();
                } else {
                    questionCount = 0;
                    String message = "Ha completado su prueba " + 
                            student.getName() + ".  Su puntaje de prueba es " +
                            student.getPuntos() + ".";
                    clearStudentPanel(message);
                    ProyectoFinal.this.student = null;
                    
                    CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) mainPanel.getLayout();
                    layout.show(mainPanel, "Student");
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateTablePanel() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
            tableModel.removeRow(0);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getStudents().size(); i++) {
            Student student = model.getStudents().get(i);
            Object[] object = new Object[tableModel.getColumnCount()];
            object[0] = student.getCedula();
            object[1] = student.getName();
            object[2] = student.getRescorrect();
            object[3] = student.getPuntos();
            object[4] = student.getStatus();
            tableModel.addRow(object);
        }
    }
    
    public JPanel createTablePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        String[] header = { "Estudiante No", "Nombre", "Rescorrect", 
                "Puntos Obtenidos", "Status" };
        
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
                if (c < 2) {
                    return String.class;
                } else {
                    return Integer.class;
                }
            }
        };
        
        for (String string : header) {
            tableModel.addColumn(string);
        }
        
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Regresar a las pruebas de los estudiantes");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                questionCount = 0;
                clearStudentPanel("");
                ProyectoFinal.this.student = null;
                
                CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) mainPanel.getLayout();
                layout.show(mainPanel, "Student");
            }
        });
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class ProjectModel {
        
        private List<Student> students;
        private List<Question> questions;
        
        public ProjectModel() {
            this.students = new ArrayList<>();
            this.questions = createQuestionsFactory();
        }
        
        private List<Question> createQuestionsFactory() {
            List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
            
            String question = "En programacion, una variable es?";
            String[] answers = { "Informacion Almacenada", "Un numero",
                    "Un Contador" };
            String correctAnswer = "Informacion Almacenada";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 6));
            
            question = "Que es un hacker?";
            answers = new String[] { "Un delincuente informatico", 
                    "Un programa de Facebook",
                    "Experto en Tecnologia" };
            correctAnswer = "Experto en Tecnologia";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 6));
            
            question = "Que es un malware?";
            answers = new String[] { "Software Malicioso", "Virus de Celular",
                    "Un Trino de un Politico en Campaña" };
            correctAnswer = "Software Malicioso";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 6));
            
            question = "Que es Python?";
            answers = new String[] { "Una Serpiente", "Un Lenguaje de Programacion",
                    "Un arma" };
            correctAnswer = "Un Lenguaje de Programacion";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 6));
            
            question = "La Ram es?";
            answers = new String[] { "Capacidad de almacenamiento", 
                    "Chip de ayuda al Procesador",
                    "Rama de la tecnologia que estudia el hardware" };
            correctAnswer = "Chip de ayuda al Procesador";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 6));
            
            question = "Que es minecraft?";
            answers = new String[] { "VideoJuego de supervivencia", 
                    "Metodo chino de almacenamiento de datos",
                    "Bomba atomica" };
            correctAnswer = "VideoJuego de supervivencia";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 6));
            
            question = "Que es el machine learning?";
            answers = new String[] { "Enseñar a las maquinas a hacer cosas", 
                    "Programar maquinas para que usen algoritmos",
                    "Todo aquello que podemos aprender de una maquina" };
            correctAnswer = "Programar maquinas para que usen algoritmos";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 6));
            
            question = "Que es Realidad Aumentada?";
            answers = new String[] { "Tecnologia de inmersion", 
                    "Protocolo de Mejora a la vista humana",
                    "Vision de un entorno fisico al mundo real, a "
                    + "traves de un dispositivo" };
            correctAnswer = "Vision de un entorno fisico al mundo "
                    + "real, a traves de un dispositivo";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 6));
            
            question = "Para que se utilizan los Bit-Coins?";
            answers = new String[] { "Apostar en Casinos", 
                    "Realizar Pagos Online de forma segura",
                    "Comprar entradas de cine" };
            correctAnswer = "Realizar Pagos Online de forma segura";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 6));
            
            question = "Que es un String?";
            answers = new String[] { "Una variable de tipo cadena", "Una cuerda",
                    "Un culumpio" };
            correctAnswer = "Una variable de tipo cadena";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 6));
            
            question = "El orden de los factores no altera?";
            answers = new String[] { "La Formula Cuadratica", "El Producto",
                    "La Division" };
            correctAnswer = "El Producto";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 4));
            
            question = "En la jerarquia de Operadores, cual de los "
                    + "siguientes signos tiene prioridad?";
            answers = new String[] { "*", "-", "+" };
            correctAnswer = "*";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 4));
            
            question = "Cuanto vale Pi?";
            answers = new String[] { "3.1315", "3.1514", "3.1415" };
            correctAnswer = "3.1415";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 4));
            
            question = "Como se denomina un Triangulo con sus 3 lados iguales?";
            answers = new String[] { "Isosceles", "Escaleno", "Equilatero" };
            correctAnswer = "Equilatero";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 4));
            
            question = "Como se denomina un Triangulo con sus 3 lados diferentes?";
            answers = new String[] { "Isosceles", "Escaleno", "Equilatero" };
            correctAnswer = "Escaleno";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 4));
            
            question = "What does the abbreviation DOB stand for?";
            answers = new String[] { "Date of Birth", "Date of Bird",
                    "Donuts Online Business" };
            correctAnswer = "Date of Birth";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 4));
            
            question = "What is the plural form for child?";
            answers = new String[] { "Childs", "Childes", "Children" };
            correctAnswer = "Children";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 4));
            
            question = "The English Language originates from?";
            answers = new String[] { "United States", "Great Britain",
                    "Germany" };
            correctAnswer = "Germany";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 4));
            
            question = "What is the singular form of the verb \"to be\"?";
            answers = new String[] { "Is", "Are", "Am" };
            correctAnswer = "Is";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 4));
            
            question = "What is TOEFL?";
            answers = new String[] { "Test of English as a foreign language", "An STD",
                    "A cookie brand" };
            correctAnswer = "Test of English as a foreign language";
            questions.add(new Question(question, createList(answers), correctAnswer, 4));
            
            return questions;
        }
        
        private List<String> createList(String[] values) {
            List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
            
            for (String s : values) {
                output.add(s);
            }
            
            return output;
        }

        public List<Student> getStudents() {
            return students;
        }

        public void addStudent(Student student) {
            this.students.add(student);
        }

        public List<Question> getQuestions() {
            return questions;
        }
        
        public Question getQuestion(int index) {
            return questions.get(index);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Question {
        
        private final int puntos;
        
        private final List<String> answers;
        
        private final String correctAnswer;
        private final String question;
        
        public Question(String question, List<String> answers, 
                String correctAnswer, int puntos) {
            this.question = question;
            this.answers = answers;
            this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
            this.puntos = puntos;
        }

        public List<String> getAnswers() {
            return answers;
        }
        
        public String getAnswer(int index) {
            return answers.get(index);
        }
        
        public List<String> getShuffledAnswers() {
            Collections.shuffle(answers);
            return answers;
        }

        public boolean isAnswerCorrect(String answer) {
            return answer.equals(correctAnswer);
        }

        public String getQuestion() {
            return question;
        }

        public int getPuntos() {
            return puntos;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Student {
        
        private int puntos;
        private int rescorrect;
        
        private final String name;
        private final String cedula;
        
        public Student(String cedula, String name) {
            this.cedula = cedula;
            this.name = name;
            this.puntos = 0;
            this.rescorrect = 0;
        }

        public int getPuntos() {
            return puntos;
        }

        public void addPuntos(int puntos) {
            this.puntos += puntos;
        }

        public int getRescorrect() {
            return rescorrect;
        }

        public void addRescorrect() {
            this.rescorrect++;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return (puntos >= 71) ? 1 : 0;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getCedula() {
            return cedula;
        }
        
    }

}
```