# Why is the graphics disappearing from CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am brand new to coding and this community has been very beneficial. This is my first time asking after reading different related questions I still don't seem to get it.

So, when I hit loginButton (setup in another class called LoginPage) it shows the "welcomePage" card, the welcomePage (card) has two buttons backButton and drawButton. Jpanel is the main container, added to a Jframe (also set up in class LoginPage). I am trying to paint and setbackground(color); on the welcomePage when a drawButton is clicked, but for some reason, the paint shows and disappears immediately while the background changes. Also when I put the paintComponent(welcomepanel.getGraphics()); method in a while loop without "break;", the paint does stay but the window gets stuck (doesn't close) and the background doesn't change (why is that?).

```
public class WelcomePage  implements ActionListener{

 JPanel welcomepanel = new JPanel();
JButton backButton = new JButton("Back");
JButton drawButton = new JButton("DRAW");

//Other codes elided

WelcomePage (String userID) {
 drawButton.addActionListener(this);

backButton.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 25);

    backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            LoginPage.cardLayout.show(LoginPage.container, "loginpage");



        }
    });

    drawButton.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 25);

    drawButton.addActionListener(this);

   welcomepanel.setSize(420, 420);

    welcomepanel.add(backButton); //backs to the previous page (card)
    welcomepanel.add(drawButton);


 } //end constructor

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


     g = welcomepanel.getGraphics();

            g.drawString("CHASE", 200, 90);

            g.setColor(Color.yellow);

            for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {

                    if (row % 2 == col % 2) {
                        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                    } else
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g.fillRect(100 + col * 40, 100 + row * 40, 40, 40);
                }

            }


}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("DRAW")) {

        welcomepanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        paintComponent(welcomepanel.getGraphics());
     // while (true) {paintComponent(welcomepanel.getGraphics());}


        welcomepanel.repaint();

        welcomepanel.revalidate();

    }
}

} //end class WelcomePage
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried extending the welcompage to Jpanel and directly drawing on it and that works but I instead want a particular instance of Jpanel (welcomepanel) to get the drawing.

[This is what the paint looks like when welcome page extends Jpanel or when I use: while (true) {paintComponent(welcomepanel.getGraphics());}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvnF7.png)

My second question is,  I want to ultimately create a GUI that "teachers" would use to add Quiz type questions and Students would use to take those quizzes, I'd determine who is who based on their login credentials or combo box selection or something. Is it a good idea to navigate through the different activities using CardLayout and with Jpanel as the main container or should I use something else?

Update:**Update this time I used anonymous class in actionperformed method but when the drawButton is clicked still doesn't draw:**

WelcomePage.java:

```
 import javax.swing.*; import java.awt.*; import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class WelcomePage implements ActionListener {

    JPanel welcomepanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel("QUIZ");
    JButton backButton = new JButton("Back");

    
    JButton drawButton = new JButton("DRAW");
    JButton whiteButton = new JButton("white");


    WelcomePage(String userID) {

        ///super();
        //  welcomepanel.setLayout(new GroupLayout(welcomepanel));
        welcomeLabel.setBounds(100, 0, 200, 35);
        welcomeLabel.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 25));
        welcomeLabel.setText("Welcome " + userID);

        backButton.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 25);
        // backButton.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.SOUTH);

        backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loginPage.cardLayout.show(loginPage.container, "loginpage");


            }
        });


        drawButton.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 25);

        drawButton.addActionListener(this);

        whiteButton.setBounds(200, 200, 100, 25);

        whiteButton.addActionListener(this);

        welcomepanel.setSize(420, 420);


        welcomepanel.add(welcomeLabel);
        welcomepanel.add(backButton);
        welcomepanel.add(drawButton);
        welcomepanel.add(whiteButton);


    }



    /**
     * Invoked when an action occurs.
     *
     * @param e the event to be processed
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("DRAW")) {

            welcomepanel = new JPanel() {

                @Override
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                    super.paintComponent(g);

                    g.drawString("CHASE", 200, 90);

                    g.setColor(Color.yellow);

                    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
                        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {

                            if (row % 2 == col % 2) {
                                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                            } else
                                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                            g.fillRect(100 + col * 40, 100 + row * 40, 40, 40);

                        }

                    }

                }

            };


            welcomepanel.setBackground(Color.black);

            welcomepanel.repaint();

            welcomepanel.revalidate();


            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("white")) {
                welcomepanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
            }
        }
    }
```

I created a new instance of the welcomepage in the actionperformed method in the following class and called welcomepages' welcomePanel to get a "welcome page" that greats the user. All I wanted is when I hit the drawButton the paintcomponent method to get executed as defined in welcomepages'  actionperformed method. I wanted to explore the possibility of using different Jpanels declared in a single class. Feel free to comment on any other part of my code as well.

loginPage.java:

```
  import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class loginPage implements ActionListener {

   static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   static JPanel container = new JPanel();

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();


    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");

    JButton logoutButton = new JButton("Logout");
    JButton hoemButton = new JButton("HOME");

    static CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();


    JTextField userIDField = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField userPasswordField = new JPasswordField();

    JLabel IdLabel = new JLabel("userID:");
    JLabel userPasswordLabel = new JLabel("password:");
    JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel();

    HashMap<String, String> loginInfo = new HashMap<>(); //to hold the copy of the constructors' parameter value so it can be globally available for methods such as getters

    loginPage(HashMap<String, String> copyOfLoginInfo) {

        this.loginInfo = copyOfLoginInfo;  //@parra value copied into a global variable


       // this.container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       container.setLayout(cardLayout);

        IdLabel.setBounds(50, 100, 75, 25);
        IdLabel.setLocation(50, 100);
        userIDField.setBounds(125, 100, 200, 25);

        userPasswordLabel.setBounds(50, 150, 75, 25);
        userPasswordField.setBounds(125, 150, 200, 25);

        loginButton.setBounds(125, 200, 100, 25);
        loginButton.setFocusable(false);
        loginButton.addActionListener(this);

        hoemButton.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 25);
        logoutButton.setBounds(310, 0, 100, 25);
        logoutButton.setFocusable(false);

        resetButton.setBounds(220, 200, 100, 25);
        resetButton.setFocusable(false);
        resetButton.addActionListener(this);


        messageLabel.setBounds(125, 250, 250, 35);
        messageLabel.setFont(new Font(null, Font.ITALIC, 25));

        setPanel1();


        panel1.add(loginButton);
        panel1.add(resetButton);
        panel1.add(hoemButton);
        panel1.add(IdLabel);
        panel1.add(userIDField);
        panel1.add(userPasswordLabel);
        panel1.add(userPasswordField);
        panel1.add(messageLabel);

        panel2.add(logoutButton);
        setPanel2();

        //add panals to the JPanel container with their identifier string
        container.add(panel1, "loginPageage");
        container.add(panel2, "logoutpage");





        //this show method of cardLayout determines which panel..
        // ...should be shown at the start of the application, identifier string is used here
        cardLayout.show(container, "loginPageage");


        //when login is clicked go to logout page (panal 2)

        hoemButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(container, "logoutpage");
            }
        });

        //when logout is clicked go back to loginPageage

        logoutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(container, "loginPageage");
            }
        });




        //add container to Jframe:


        frame.add(container);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(520, 520);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //sets the window in the middle of pc screen
        //frame.setLayout(null); //this will make the cardlayout not show!!
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);


    }




    /**
     * Invoked when an action occurs.
     *
     * @param e the event to be processed
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == resetButton) {

            userIDField.setText("");
            userPasswordField.setText("");
        }

        if (e.getSource() == loginButton) {

            String userID = userIDField.getText(); //gets user id text
            String password = String.valueOf(userPasswordField.getPassword()); //gets the password from the password field and then converts it into a string

            if (loginInfo.containsKey(userID)) {
                if (loginInfo.get(userID).equals(password)) {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.cyan);
                    messageLabel.setText(String.format("%30s", "Login SUCCESSFUL"));



                    WelcomePage w = new WelcomePage(userID);
                    //add instance of welcome page to the Jpanel container, and
                    container.add(w.welcomepanel, "WelcomeP");
                    cardLayout.show(container, "WelcomeP");


                }

                        else {
                    messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    messageLabel.setText(String.format("%34s", "Invalid password!"));
                }
            } else {


                messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                messageLabel.setText(String.format("%33s", "username not found!"));

            }
        }

    }

    void setPanel1() {

        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); //equivalent to setManaged(false)??
        panel1.setBounds(100, 100, 420, 420);
        panel1.setBackground(new Color(150, 150, 150));
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));


    }

    void setPanel2(){

        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); //equivalent to setManaged(false)??
        panel2.setSize(420, 420);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.green);}

}
```

UserInfo.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class UserInfo {

    HashMap<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<>();

    UserInfo () {

        credentials.put("user", "user");
    }

    protected HashMap<String, String> getCredentials() {
        return credentials;
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    UserInfo users = new UserInfo();

    loginPage loginP = new loginPage(users.getCredentials());
}
```

}

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* You don't call paintComponent directly.  You call repaint and let Swing process the paint chain.  You never call repaint or paintComponent in a loop.  This blocks the GUI thread and freezes the GUI.  As to your second question, it depends.  For the student, a CardLayout with JPanels would be fine because you control the display of the JPanels.  In other words, the student signs on, takes the quiz, gets his score, and logs off.

Comment: A teacher, on the other hand, may want to create a quiz, "take" the quiz (to see if his questions and answers are correct), and maybe look at a JTable of all of the students' scores for a quiz.  A JTabbedPane might be more appropriate.  You might want to take a look at this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65297470/i-have-a-problem-using-jframe-to-print-a-table-for-multiple-arrays/65484936#65484936).  It creates a similar GUI to the one you want, although in the answer, the text is Spanish.

Comment: Also when you override paintcomponent always call `super.paintComponent(g);` as the first statement in the overriden method.  Also keep your questions to 1 per post, as asking multiple because less useful to others

Comment: Also looking at the code `paintComponent` is not even overriding a valid method as your class is not a `JPanel` Id suggest posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for better help sooner.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thank you for that link, exactly what I needed, I also have classes setup such as abstract class Questions and subclasses true/false and multi-choice... having the teacher test the Quiz is also a great idea!

As for not calling paintComponent directly, so what are my choices? I called welcomepanel.paintComponents(g); as the first statement in the paintComponent method as DavidKroukamp suggested and I called welcomepanel.repaint(); in the actionPerformed method. Now I can see that the paintComponent method is never used as opposed to when I directly called it.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp So, if my class isn't derived, I couldn't use the paintComponent method? And a Jpanel reference variable instead of "super"?  I am having a problem accomplishing what I want with that anyways. I am just trying to get myself comfortable with how things work, I even tried an anonymous class inside the actionperformed method and assigned it to welcompanel (here I used "super" in the overridden method). I just can't figure out why it isn't working at the click of a button without extending the whole class to Jpanel :(  I will post all the codes in a little while.

Comment: Don't use getGraphics() to do custom painting. See: [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples on how to do custom painting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of what you might want to refactor your code to look like (I have omitted non-essential code that you had in your example) in order to get it working. Most notably you will see I use a `JPanel` and *override* `paintComponent` of the *panel* , call `super.paintComponent` and then do all the drawing work inside there. Also I override `getPreferredSize` in order to size the `JPanel` correctly instead of `setSize`.

**Update:**

As per your comment:

*first I wanted the panel to appear with just the buttons and then when I hit the drawButton then I want the drawing to appear.*:

Simply create a boolean `canDraw` that is initially set to *false*, in `paintComponent` before drawing check the `canDraw` booleans value and return if it is *false*. Then in the *draw* buttons `ActionListener` do `canDraw = true;`, and then call `welcomPanel.repaint();` which will cause `paintComponent` to be called and thus because the `canDraw` is *true* it should draw the graphics as opposed to returning.

Some other points to keep in mind are:

1. Don't use a `null`/`AbsoluteLayout` rather use an appropriate [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
2. Don't call `setBounds()` or `setSize()`  on components, if you use a correct layout manager this will be handled for you
3. All Swing components should be called on the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` (perhaps you do this, but I put it here to be safe)
4. Call `JFrame#pack()` before setting the frame to visible

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class WelcomePage {

    boolean canDraw = false;
    private JPanel welcomePanel;

    public WelcomePage() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(WelcomePage::new);
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("WelcomePage");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // lets use a panel to hold our buttons which has a FlowLayoout and thus we dont need setSize or setBounds
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton backButton = new JButton("Back");
        JButton drawButton = new JButton("DRAW");
        drawButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                canDraw = true;
                // repaint will call jpanels paintComponent
                welcomePanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        buttonsPanel.add(backButton);
        buttonsPanel.add(drawButton);

        welcomePanel = new JPanel() {
            // override paintComponent of jpanel
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                // only draw when this is true
                if (!canDraw) {
                    return;
                }

                g.drawString("CHASE", 200, 90);
                g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                        if (row % 2 == col % 2) {
                            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                        } else {
                            g.setColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                        g.fillRect(100 + col * 40, 100 + row * 40, 40, 40);
                    }

                }
            }

            // override getPreferredSize of jpanel to provide the correct size based on the drawing in paintComponent
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(600, 600);
            }
        };

        frame.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(welcomePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but my problem wasn't drawing it on the panel like that (I already did that).  At first I wanted the panel to appear with just the buttons and then when I hit the drawButton then I want the drawing to appear. I am guessing my problem is how I am using the paintcomponent method, if you see the update I made, without the anonymous class the draw button changes background color fine, but with the anonymous method, it neither changes background nor draws the paint. How exactly would you associate the "drawBuyton" with the paintcomponent method?

Comment: I will follow your advice and refactor my code and hope it works, thank you I didn't paid attention to your suggestions at the beginning!

Comment: @Faisaljemil pretty simple. Have a boolean called `canDraw` which is set to false. Inside the `paintComponent` method simply check if `canDraw` is true, if not return, otherwise draw. Then on your button actionlistener simply set the boolean to true and call `welcomePanel.repaint();` which will cause the `paintComponent` method to be called again and this time the boolean will be true and your logic should then draw the stuff

Comment: As for "having it working" that's debatable, the way you used and created the graphics and the panel and buttons are not 100% within swings best practices but hopefully you can learn and incorporate some of them as I have shown

Comment: @Faisaljemil Updated my answer to address your question of *t first I wanted the panel to appear with just the buttons and then when I hit the drawButton then I want the drawing to appear.*

Comment: Thank you bro, i can't believe it was as simple as using a boolean var! **"the way you used and created the graphics and the panel and buttons are not 100% within swings best practices"** lol, I am learning, it has just been 3 months for me, just practicing to see how the codes interplay  :)   
 If I want multiple panels, is it better to do all the individual construction of the panels in different methods or in different constructors? Also, is it preferable to add ActionListener as you did right after the new button was created? The way you instantiated the welcomePanel was pretty cool!

Comment: @Faisaljemil glad you got it working. And no hate man, as long as you are open to learning and actually take what I've said and others have into account you will only get better and better. I've seen too many posters here not listen to any advice and I doubt they have got far. As for your other questions, I'd suggest each `JPanel` is declared in its own class/file I.e. `public class SomeJPanel extends JPanel {}`  thus you separate your concerns and your code is more clean and concise.

Comment: Then when you want to use the panel you simply do `JPanel somePanel = new SomePanel();` and add that to your cards as for where and how to do the ActionListener that's up to you, however I prefer grouping my codes concerns so that it's not wild and all over the place

Comment: As for they way I created welcompanel it's helpful if there isn't much code but should the code grow larger you might want it in its own class/file

Comment: Noted! Thanks for your time and advice!